# Output stage using 2 transistors

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, current, output, darlington

I want to understand how does this 2-transistor circuit work. It is used in a schematic for increasing the current rating at the discrete output stage. This does not look like a standard darlington configuration. Is there any specific benefit of this 2-transistor circuit over a standard darlington pair? Can we remove 'R2' from the circuit? It looks like not doing any useful work. Also what can be the benefit of 'C1' capacitor?

[image: Output stage]

Comment: availability and selection. I dont think I have seen a PNP darlington before. they would be hard to come by

Comment: @DKNguyen [587 PNP Darlingtons](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/transistors-bipolar-bjt-single/276?k=pnp%20darlington)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't a Darlington configuration, because T1's collector is tied directly to ground, rather than to T2's collector.

The advantage is that T2 can fully saturate, reducing its C-E voltage drop and power dissipation.

R2 serves to keep both transistors off when the input connection is open, and you should keep it.

C1 probably doesn't do anything very useful. It limits the rate of change of the voltage on the collector of T2 when it shuts off (depending on the load current), but it also means that extra current must flow through T2 when it turns on. If it is needed at all, it would probably be better to connect C1 directly between the output terminal and ground.

Comment: I have a doubt. If input is open,  will T2 float? Because base has no pull up connection to Vcc.

Comment: @MeenieLeis: It's a legitimate concern, and an additional resistor across the B-E junction of T2 would eliminate any leakage current there. But in practice, T2 is not all that sensitive to leakage, and its base voltage is clamped through the B-E junction of T1 and R2 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> This does not look like a standard darlington configuration

I still think of this circuit as a Darlington configuration as the \$\beta\$s of the transistors are multiplied.

The only significant difference I see with the "original" Darlington circuit is that the collector of the first transistor isn't connected to the collector of the second transistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFO18a.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the right circuit R5 is needed to limit the base current through Q3.

But both circuit "multiply \$\beta\$" and so in that respect the circuit could qualify as a "Darlington". If you think a Darlington needs the collector of the input transistor connected to the output (left circuit) then the right circuit is **not** a Darlington.

Capacitor C1 is very likely added for suppressing switching artifacts (high frequency signal spikes).

Answer (score 1):

What they said.
The following has some added material plus some restatement of what other answers have already said.

A "real" Darlington pair with T1 collector connected to T2 collector has the simultaneous advantage and DISadvantage of not fully saturating due to base drive being removed from T2 as its Vce falls to around 1 Vbe.

This lack of saturation has the obvious disadvantage of a minimum on "saturation" voltage of somewhere over 0.5V and the advantage of Q1 not needing to come out of saturation at turn off , thus improving the switching speed.
In another age the latter feature was valuable. Nowadays far less so.

Your shown arrangement does not have this 'feature' so T2 can saturate and also is slow in turnoff. As they have made no effort to turn T2 off rapidly (eg no resistor from T2 base to V+) the turnoff speed is apparently not an issue here and the saturation issue may matter. EXCEPT that D1 effectively 'restores' the removed saturation drop. It does however move the dissipation out of T2 into D1, which seems unlikely to be important, but may be.

Now that T1 can saturate due to always available base drive, R3 is now needed to limit this drive.

IF Vin was never floating then R2 would not strictly be needed but is usually a good idea.  In this case the input conditions are explicitly stated as open/ground (= open/low) so in the open state R2 is needed as a pullup. They have made R2 about 20% of R1 - perhaps in an attempt to limit base current while still maintaining a good turn off pull-up current. Any speed gain from this low pullup value is largely wasted due to the lack of a T2 base pullup.